# MSBuildExtensionsPath32 not set correctly?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild

For the life of me, I cannot find where this value is actually set.  It SHOULD be pointing at C:\Program Files\MSBuild, but on our build box, it's pointing at C:.  How can I change this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`MSBuildExtensionsPath32` is set internally by MSBuild. (`BuildEngine.BuildPropertyGroup.SetExtensionsPathProperties`)

But you could override it by setting an environment variable.

```
SET MSBuildExtensionsPath="C:\Program Files\MSBuild"
```

Or you could override the value in your project file :

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuildExtensionsPath>C:\Users\madgnome\Desktop\msbuild</MSBuildExtensionsPath>

  <!-- It works too with relative path -->
  <!--<MSBuildExtensionsPath>..\msbuild</MSBuildExtensionsPath>-->
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  I played around with the SET command, and this got me past that error, but introduced another.  I think I'm going to pass it off to my architect and see what he comes with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but I ran into a similar issue using MSBuild version 16.0 ("equivalent" to Visual Studio 2019).

In my case I had a commandline option setting the build tools to an older version that didn't exist on my build server.

I had to use `/tv:"Current"` to get the build to correctly set the `MSBuildExtensionsPath` variable

Comment: Yeah, MSBuild was and is a bit of a hot mess. It's definitely better with .NET Core, though... but I still wish that Microsoft had been able to get the project.json system to work. Alas.

Comment: Yeah, especially since the documentation is incomplete - in the case of the docs I was looking at, `"Current"` wasn't even mentioned as a valid option. They had `4.0` listed as the newest valid option, which was what I was using.